# comparing two files, if more than three lines are different then take action

Tags: shell

I have a script running which alerts me to changes in the two files. I need to amend it as three lines change all the time - so it isn't entirely accurate. I have sed removing the lines that change, but it's a little problematic (the lines that change move around the place, sometimes on line 1-3, sometimes lines 8-11).

I have it running an if/then/else statement:

```
if diff file1 file2 >/dev/null ; then dothis else dothis
```

doesn't work per my above explanation. so if the total number of different lines is greater than three, i need it to do the if then else statement.

one way - highly inelegant - is that i have a diff command outputting to a third file, and then a line count of that third file

```
diff file1 file2 > file3
wc -l file3
```

file3 returns

```
10 file3
```

this is a bit messy, but will work... but i don't know how to write a statement that will look at file3 and return a match if the line '10 file3' begins with a number > 10....

i am sure there's a far easier way to do this. no idea how though. thanks as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help you at all if I understand your problem correctly?

```
if [ `diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' \
    file1 file2 | wc -l` -eq 3 ];
then
    echo foo
else
    echo bar
fi
```

This allows you to test the exact number of changed lines, the example testing to equals three. In your case, you would then use -gt 3?

Or did I understand the problem incorrectly?

Hannu

Comment: works well, thankyou! i just came up with another solution searching for and removing strings, and including the diff -w command. but thanks, this is far better! good man.